# Calling from feature to features packaged as JAR

Tags: automated-tests, karate, e2e-testing

we are adopting Karate (Version: 0.9.9-RC3) as our main framework to do e2e testing in multiple projects and teams which need some common functionalities/features or scenarios to run.

We have thought about packaging a Karate Maven project as a JAR that contains these features and give the teams the chance to call this features and save them time and so on. Could be this possible?

We've tried to package some few test and call them from another feature as the following:

```
Feature: Calling packaged features in JAR

Background:

Scenario: 

* def packagedFeature = call read('promotions.jar:resources/test.feature')
```

Any hint?